# Is it necessary to grant new Android 13 - Granular media permissions to use react-native-document-picker

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, android-13

I am a `react-native` and I have been using `react-native-document-picker` almost for two years and never granted any permission to use it. I am able to pick `documents`, `Images` or `Audio files` from `Downloads`, `Documents`, and other app's folders like `WhatsappDocuments`, `whatsappImages`, audio files recorded by other apps.

But recently in Android 13 following permissions have been introduced,

```
Images and photos: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
Videos: READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
Audio files: READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
```

> Before you access another app's media files, verify that the user has
> granted the appropriate granular media permissions to your app

This line is from [Google Docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions). Do they mean files stored in App's own folder(Every app has their own folder in Android which is not accessible directly) or all files in general folders like `Downloads`, `Documents` ect

Can some clear me that Do I need to grant Android 13 - Granular media permissions or Can I continue as usual without any permissions?

Thank You.

Comment: Well did you try without already,?

Comment: If you mean permissions? Yes, I tried without permissions and I am able to upload all type of documents.